# Print String character one by one using threads

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

I am trying to print characters one by one on the animated banner, but i can't get the desired result.

I am getting the result with my code but not the one I am looking for. I am getting the banner and result of characters also.

But those characters are overlapping one another.
Please check below code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;

//Banner class
class Banner extends Frame implements Runnable 
{
    boolean stop=false;
    String str="Sreedhar Practice seassion";
    //constructor
    public Banner()
    {
        setLayout(null);
        setBackground(Color.cyan);
        setForeground(Color.blue);
    }//end of constructor

    //image paint settings methosd
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        Font f=new Font("Courier",Font.BOLD,40);
        g.setFont(f);
for (int i=0;i<=str.length() ;i++ )
        {
            char ch=str.charAt(i);
            String c=String.valueOf(ch);
            g.drawString("\t"+c,10,100);
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ie)
            {
            }
            //char ch=str.carAt(0);
            //str=str.substring(1,str.length());
            //str=str+ch;
            if (stop)
            {
                return;
            }
        }

    }//image paint settings methosd end

    //start of run method
    public void run()
    {
            if (stop)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }//end of run method

    //main method starting
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException 
    {
        Banner b=new Banner();
        b.setSize(400,400);
        b.setTitle("Sreedhar Banner");
        b.setVisible(true);
        Thread t=new Thread(b);
        t.start();
        System.in.read();
        b.stop=true;
    }//end of main method
}//end of class Banner
```

This is my code, but am not getting the desired result what i want.

Comment: @Pointy ,thanks for editing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

few bugs over here 
first:

```
}//end of run method
```

one curly brace is redundant

second:

```
for (int i=0;i<=str.length() ;i++ )
```

should be:

```
for (int i=0; i < str.length(); i++)
```

third:

```
g.drawString("\t" + c, 10 + PRINT_FACTOR * i, 100);
```

where PRINT_FACTOR should be counted or choosed by expirement

Comment: Thanks for your use full comment

Comment: I am facing another problem in my banner it is not printing all characters. it just printing some characters on that String file will you please check it once

Answer (score 0):

It seems like in your call to `g.drawString("\t"+c,10,100);` the coordinates remain the same. Looks like it should somehow move along x axis depending on letter number. Try this:

```
int xLetterDifference = 6;
g.drawString("\t"+c, 10 + xLetterDifference  * i ,100);
```

And alter value of xLetterDifference to adjust distance between letters

Comment: Thank you for giving the answer.